# How to display the params on the web (React Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following js

App.js

```
<LayoutRoute
 exact
 path="/analysis/:id"
 layout={MainLayout}
 component={AnalysisPage}
/>
```

index.js

```
<IconWidget
 title="companyA"
 subtitle="Top Product Trade: Pen"
 color="info"
 onClick={()=>{window.location='analysis/companyA'}}
/>
```

analysis.js

```
function analysisPage({match}){
  console.log(match)
  return(
    <div>
    {"${match.params.id}"}
    </div>
  )
}
const AnalysisPage= () => {
  return(
   <div>
     Company: {this.analysisPage}
   </div>
export default AnalysisPage;
```

I have applied react router in the App.js which can redirect the website from index.js to analysis.js by pressing the button.
However, I would like to display the params to the div. I took reference from  https://alligator.io/react/react-router-parameters however, it doesn't work. I would like to know what have I did wrong? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the props:

```
Company: {this.analysisPage(this.props)}
```

So that `match` params could be used:

```
function analysisPage({match}){
```

Comment: HI I would like to know why it shows TypeError: _this.analysisPage is not a function

Comment: why underscore in `this`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
this.props.match.params.id
```